# Surface integral - How to parameterize efficiently

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

I have a question regarding parameterization of surface integrals.
How do I know which parameter I input?
Lets say I have the Tetrahedron with:
$x+y+z=1$
bounded by $z=0$, $y=0$, $x=0$.
My teacher did this parameterization:
$x=u$
$y=v$
$z=0$.
How do I know when to do parameterization like that:
$x=ucos(v)$
$y=usin(v)$
z=something.
Or something like the $x=u$, $y=v$ and such..
Any tip will be welcomed.

Comment: If an area is rectangular, Cartesian coordinates are recommended. If an area is circular, polar coordinates are recommended.

Comment: Problem is, how do I know which area looks like? lets say I have shapes that I dont know, like the Tetrahedron, Paraboloid, and such ( I know some, but there are some shapes I dont know how they look like ).
Is there a way to know exactly what to do? or its a do and try thingy. And if it is a do and try, how do I know if it will fail \ succed?